# Generar PDF con input

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy generando una sección en una pagina donde el usuario tendra que ingresar un numero de serie desde un input y luego dar click a un botón para generar un pdf.
Ya tengo el PDF con el diseño.

quiero saber si es posible que con el pdf que ya tengo diseñado se inserte tambien la información que coloquen en el input

Vi las opciones de jsPDF y html2PDF

Comment: tienes doompdf, si mal no recuerdo, generas el pdf desde etiquetas html y al ejecutar doompdf insertas las variables que vayan en dicho pdf

Comment: Y otra cosa, veo que comentas "Vi las opciones", probaste alguna? tienes alguna duda? con decir "quiero saber si es posible" no es una buena pregunta porque eso quiere decir que no lo has intentado

Comment: Es posible? Sí. Es posible.